# Tree to list (updated)

Tags: tree, prolog, flatten, dcg

I tried a suggestion from someone's comment in another post on how to change a tree into a list. However, I have an undeclared variables somewhere (or something), so my values in my list are [_G667, _G673, _G679], instead of [5, 2, 6], which is the correct answer. All of the manipulations are correct, to my knowledge.

Here is the code:

```
flatten( Item , []).

flatten( tree(Left, Val, Right), List) :-
  flatten(Left, List1),
  append(List1, [E], List2),
  flatten(Right, List3),
  append(List2, List3, List).
```

The query that I used was:

```
?- flatten(tree(tree(nil, 2, nil), 5, tree(nil, 6, nil)), L).
```

Does anyone see the variable issue? I thought it might be in the first line (with Item), but if I change Item to item, the query immediately returns false.

I have only written a few Prolog programs, so this is still a new concept to me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `E` should be change to `Val`. As it stands, `Val` is not used (!) and `E` comes from nowhere.

Also, for it to work, you should change `Item` to `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues. Let's start with the most fundamental one: You are having a tree which is of the following type.

```
is_tree(nil).
is_tree(tree(L,_E,R)) :-
   is_tree(L),
   is_tree(R).
```

Your program should reflect that type. Have I said 'type'? Well, `is_tree/1` is a predicate as any other.

The other issue is your heavy use of `append/3`.  Not without reason, many Prolog systems do not offer `append/3` because it is often preferable to formulate the concatenation with the help of [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)s.

```
tree_elements(nil) --> [].
tree_elements(tree(L,E,R)) -->
   tree_elements(L),
   [E],
   tree_elements(R).
```

Now you can use this

```
?- phrase(tree_elements(tree(tree(nil, 2, nil), 5, tree(nil, 6, nil))), Es).
   Es = [2,5,6].
```

Comment: this does not answer what the OP has asked.

Answer (score 2):

What @aioobe said. I think you're also using `append/3` more than you ought. Assuming your tree representation looks like:

```
tree( Left_subtree, Data , Right_subtree )
```

with the atom `nil` representing an empty tree, I believe you could achieve the same effect thusly:

```
flatten( nil , [] ).
flatten( tree( Left , Data , Right ) , Flat ) :-
  flatten( Left  , Pfx ) ,
  flatten( Right , Sfx ) ,
  append( Pfx , [Data|Sfx] , Flat  )
  .
```